# How can I use AAD for an Azure version of "Windows Authentication" from a Web App to a Web API App?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have two applications:

1. MVC Site (User-facing Web App secured via OAuth -> Google)
2. Web API Site ("Private" Web Services)

These are hosted in an App Service Plan in Azure. These web services will only be consumed by my own applications - I don't need to worry about outside consumption. In fact, I specifically don't want outside consumption. My Web App is using OAuth to Google - that shouldn't matter here.

So to get to the heart of my question: My web services currently have no authentication/authorization model in the code but I don't want it just publicly available to anybody. On prem, we just lock this down via IIS using Windows Auth and set the service account for the consuming web app to run as a user that Windows Auth allows access to. I'd like to do the equivalent in Azure.

I understand Azure isn't exactly the same but I have to believe this is possible. I have even gotten my web services locked down the way I want using the settings in the Authentication/Authorization tab (I can try to navigate to it but I only get my Swagger UI once I login with a valid organizational account). So half of my battle is solved but I cannot figure out how to do the other half - the equivalent of setting the service account for my consuming MVC application to run as.

Can I do this via the portal without having to code specifically to this scenario? I'd really like a PaaS-level or IaaS-level solution for the security portion of consuming the above locked-down services. I'm also open to other avenues if I'm going down the wrong path in having a PaaS or IaaS security solution to this problem. I'm not against making code changes - we did have a one-liner in our RestSharp code to engage Windows Authentication, but the bulk of the work/configuration was outside of code and that's what I'm going for here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If going the IaaS path you can host the application inside of an VM in the exact same way as you did before when running it directly on-top of IIS. The benefit is that you can get running the same way as before but you will still need to manage the VM; i.e install updates and take care of its security.

However, if you want to have a PaaS solution, then you need to modify the code of your front-end application to pass on the authentication token to the back-end API, assuming the back-end accepts the same authentication as the front-end. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-get-started/ as an example on how to pass on authentication information from one app to another.

Alternatively you can use the app identity to make calls to your back-end API. This way the calls are not related to any user but are instead done in the context of the app. See https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon for more details on how to set it up, both configuration and needed code.

If you want to allow your users to sign-in using their Google accounts then you could handle authorization to your API using the app identity (second alternative above), assuming the API is independent of the requesting users identity.

Enabling authentication for a Azure Web App directly through the menus in the Azure Portal adds Azure AD authentication in-front of your application and require your to pass an access token generated by Azure AD to your API for it to work.

Comment: I definitely want PaaS hosting of my software. I brought up IaaS in case there were reasonable networking options to secure this (i.e. use a private network with only these two applications on it and pull the web services completely off the internet, but I don't see that being possible without buying the App Hosting *Environments* (not *Plans*), which seems to be a pretty big rabbit hole to go down for such a simple problem). I'll be exploring your other suggestions as soon as some updates finish on my dev box. Thanks!

Comment: I'm flagging this as an accepted answer because I believe this has the correct information on approach. I have not yet gotten this to work the way I want it to work (I'm 99% of the way there) but I have posted the details in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292678/unable-to-get-bearer-token-from-aad-to-consume-web-api